# Pegar o valor de um select_tag e colocar em uma variável

Tags: html5, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-select

Quero pegar o valor desse select_tag e colocar no message do link_to

```
<%= select_tag(:testee, options_for_select(CloneDatabaseController.find_all_models)) %>

<%= link_to('Click here', controller: 'clone_database', action: 'show', message: :testee) %>
```

Comment: Tem que fazer via Javascript, e sua outra pergunta deu certo?

Comment: não sei kkkkkkk